# How can I setup Google Analytics so it stops obtaining and showing my users city/state info?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have setup 'location' and 'geoid' to both be null, but when I logon to my Google Analytics interface I'm still seeing my test user's city/state.

How can I setup Google Analytics so it stops obtaining and showing my user's city/state info?

I have an agreement with certain users that prevents me from acquiring this information.

```
ga('myTracker.set', {
    'anonymizeIp': true,
    'referrer': null,
    'hostname': null,
    'location': null,    
    'page': docPage,

    'geoid': null
});
```

Comment: I'd reckon asking them to use adblock is out of the question?  If they're downloading any resource from a server, their IP information is being used. If you remove it from GA,  there are still hundreds of other servers and services involved that have the IP address recorded in a log file